# Bluetooth can detect headphones but can't connect

Tags: bluetooth, 20.04, macbook-pro

I've just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my 13 inch 2015 MacBook Pro. When I go to the Bluetooth section in Settings, I can see my wireless headphones listed. The headphones are in their pairing mode, but when I click it on list it never connects. I've tried with three different sets of Bluetooth headphones (Airpods Pro, Airpods, and Bose QC35). What should I do to get my laptop to connect to Bluetooth devices? I know that Bose QC35 headphones work because I've used them with my desktop running 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

For weird problems like not being able to connect to Bluetooth devices from your MacBook Pro, sometimes the solution is just to reset the SMC. Once I did that and restarted I was able to connect my headphones. This resulted in stuttering audio through my headphones, which I've "fixed" (fingers crossed) by restarting the bluetooth service. So everything is working well now. :)

Comment: Please expand. It is not at all clear what procedure you followed. (Preferably in the form of command line code.)